# Filling numpy matrix with function calculated over iterables

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I've been looking for a compact way to create a matrix calculated applying the same function to element from different iterables of different size. Say one is size m = 3 and one is size n = 4

```
a = range(3)
b = range(4)
```

And this is just the simplest example as I would be free to use numpy vectors to do the same.

And I wanna fill the matrix in this way:

```
yawn = np.zeros((len(a), len(b)), dtype='float')

meh = lambda x, y: np.exp(x + y) / (1 + np.exp(x + y))
for i in a:
    for j in b:
       yawn[i,j] = meh(i,j)
```

And the expected results is indeed:

```
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.73105858,  0.88079708,  0.95257413],
       [ 0.73105858,  0.88079708,  0.95257413,  0.98201379],
       [ 0.88079708,  0.95257413,  0.98201379,  0.99330715]])
```

I tried to use something like [np.vectorize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) or [np.fromfunction()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) and I'm getting close:

```
meh_vec = np.vectorize(meh)
meh_vec(a, 3)

array([ 0.95257413,  0.98201379,  0.99330715])
```

But I can figure out if there is a way to do something like this:

```
meh_vec(a, b)
```

which wouldn't result in a ValueError:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,)
>   (4,)

Moreover I read that:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not
>   for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Is there a workaround who might be more compact and faster than a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert those to `open` arrays that are broadcastable against each other for a resultant `2D` array with `np.ix_` -

```
In [57]: x,y = np.ix_(a,b)

In [58]: np.exp(x + y) / (1 + np.exp(x + y))
Out[58]: 
array([[0.5       , 0.73105858, 0.88079708, 0.95257413],
       [0.73105858, 0.88079708, 0.95257413, 0.98201379],
       [0.88079708, 0.95257413, 0.98201379, 0.99330715]])
```

Alternatively, to be more explicit about it, we can extend the dimensions manually with `None/np.newaxis` on the array version of inputs -

```
In [64]: a = np.arange(3)
    ...: b = np.arange(4)

In [65]: np.exp(a[:,None] + b) / (1 + np.exp(a[:,None] + b))
Out[65]: 
array([[0.5       , 0.73105858, 0.88079708, 0.95257413],
       [0.73105858, 0.88079708, 0.95257413, 0.98201379],
       [0.88079708, 0.95257413, 0.98201379, 0.99330715]])
```

To optimize further, we might want to store `np.exp(a[:,None] + b)` and re-use for the division. Also, `a[:,None] + b` could be re-written as `np.add.outer(a,b)` as that's basically an outer addition.